# “agrep” for Android Terminal?

Tags: installation, terminal, command-line

How can I do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55879578/9214072) *(agrep)* in the Android Terminal?

This program allows elastic text searching, which means that `searchqwery` would match `searchquery`, and searching `Android` would also match `Anfroid` or `Androis`.

How can I install it so that it can be run from the Android Terminal?

Comment: you need to compile a static binary for your architecture from source. this can be done with Linux Deploy https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/agrep

Comment: Not sure if it has that, but worth a try: the Termux app is an Android terminal that a.o. comes with `apt` and a lot of packages to be installed that way. It might have the `agrp` package in its repository.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Izzy, Termux has a wide repository of Linux packages, but `agrep` isn't among them so far. So you have to go for compiling the binary from [source](https://github.com/Wikinaut/agrep), or you may give [this one](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=6006931924117931213) a try. It's a static binary for `aarch64` architecture.